# REST endpoints gives 404 response after upgrading spring boot from 1.5 to 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test, rest-assured

I upgraded from using SpringBoot 1.5 to 2, using the guidelines provided in
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide

I got 401 response with the following errors while running my Test classes initially.

> There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id “null”

I fixed it using instructions provided in below link.
https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-security-there-is-no-passwordencoder-mapped-for-the-id-null/

Now, I am not getting unauthorized error but instead I am getting 404 not found response when calling a GET REST endpoint from my Test Classes using RestAssured. This is happening for all my endpoints.
Below is the snapshot of the code from my test class.

```
    Response response = given().contentType("application/json")
            .auth().preemptive().basic("myuser", "mypassword")
            .when().get(MY_URL);
```

The endpoint was working fine before the upgrade.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: 404 is a resource not found error, are the services deployed and working fine ? Have u tested this with postman ? Also try logging the request and response using log().all() after given() and then()

Comment: @Keith, did you get the solution for this? I am facing the same issue, can you please suggest me with possible reason?

Comment: Any solution for this?